# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path of an ForwardConfig cannot be null

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am getting

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path of an    ForwardConfig cannot be null
```

In struts 1.2 for `<hmtl :error>` when my form bean class validate method returns error object of ActionErrors class.

Comment: What you have done so far when you get such error?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally this Exception is encountered when you don't specify a path,validate and input in *struts-config.xml*. We need to specify where to be forwarded, in case of a failure.

```
<action path="/somePath"
       name="someForm"
       type="SomeActionClass"
       validate="true"
       input="/some.jsp">
    <forward name="success" path="/some.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

Comment: but i check struts-config.xml file numbr of times i don't think the error is in config file